# Storing time values in a database and getting the difference between two time fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am working on an application the stores time values in a database e.g Expected time of Arrival and actual time of arrival. What is the best way of storing these fields in a database?

What SQL query can I use to obtain the time difference between the two fields?

Comment: What **version** of SQL Server?? 2005 has no "TIME" datatype, while 2008 does.

Answer (score 2):

If you're on SQL Server 2008, use the `TIME` datatype. Declare those two fields

```
ExpectedTimeOfArrival TIME(7),
ActualTimeOfArrival TIME(7)
```

Read up on how to manipulate the TIME datatype [here](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/using-the-time-data-type-in-sql-server-2008).

Once you have those two fields in place, you could add a computed column to your table that calculates the difference between those two, e.g. in minutes:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable
   ADD TimeDifference AS DATEDIFF(MINUTE, ActualTimeOfArrival, ExpectedTimeOfArrival)
```

and then you could query o that new column `TimeDifference` as if it were a normal, regular table column.

Comment: Thanx Marc_s

In the from what element do I use to fill in the time field..do I use datetimepicker or a text box? If I use a text box how can i convert it to time?

Thanx

Comment: @Allan: I would probably use a textbox, and maybe back it up with a Regex validation to make sure the user enters something in the form of `hh:mm:ss` into that textbox (and otherwise reject it as invalid)